# Item dentro de comentário em PHP

Tags: php, string, comentários

[image: Captura de tela]

Se o "@return string" dentro da codificação de um arquivo PHP for apagado, a codificação sofrerá alterações significantes? Posso apagar todo comentário incluindo o "@return string"?

E por último, por que ele ficou de uma cor diferente?

Comment: Nesse caso não. isso é apenas um comentário que significa o tipo de retorno do método `errorMessage`. Você pode apagar tudo que estiver dentro do `/**` até `*/` o código continuará funcionando. A cor depende muito do tema do seu editor não tem como responder isso sem saber o tema!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo conteúdo dentro de `/* */` é um comentário e todos os comentário serão ignorados ao executar a aplicação, ou seja, eles nunca irão interferir no resultado final de alguma aplicação

Então sim você pode apagar, porém não é recomendado, pelo contrário, o melhor é inserir isso em todos outros lugares, isso explica o funcionamento, no caso, o que a função deve retornar

Comentários que começam com `/**` significa que são comentários de documentação, muitas IDEs usam esses dados que estão nesses comentários para dar mais informações da função:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No exemplo é mostrado algumas informações do parâmetro `path` da função `readFile` do JavaScript (Node.js), também observe que, apesar do javascript ser fracamente tipado, ou seja, não se define os tipos das variáveis, na descrição da função tem a informação que path deve ser uma string, number, buffer ou url. Isso é muito comum em linguagens fracamente tipadas, por exemplo, para que a pessoa saiba o que deve ser passado naquele parâmetro daquela função

Além de definir o que deve ser passado pelo parâmetro e o retorno pode ser definido o autor, versão, se está obsoleto, fazer comentários sobre o construtor e destrutor (no caso da classe)

A cor diferente é porque sua IDE reconheceu que aquilo era um comentário de documentação da função

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, Guilherme. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Não, o `@return string` é apenas documentação do método, em formato [DocBlock](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/index.html). O teu IDE e outras ferramentas, por exemplo, o [PHPDoc](https://www.phpdoc.org/), usam estes comentários especiais para te dar informação do que o código faz.

Neste caso, do `@return` está a indicar que tipo de valor a função retorna, que é string.

Podes apagar o comentário todo, mas eu recomendo que uses até esta funcionalidade para comentar o teu código pessoal.

A cor diferente é o IDE que entende PHPDoc e "pinta" diferente para indicar que é algo "especial".

Quando estás a escrever uma chamada a essa função, o IDE vai mostrar uma tooltip que vai usar esses comentários para que tu saibas como usar a mesma.

Comment: Obrigado, Leite! ;)